# python does not find module I installed

Tags: python, module, pip, python-requests

no matter I use **pip** or **pip3** to install requests, terminal always say requirement satisfied.run **python** or **python3**, then requests module not found.
use **pip list** or **pip3 list**, requests 2.26.0 is listed in the terminal. I'm using macos monterry, I'm new to python and macos, I have no idea what's wrong. A lot of thanks in advance!

Comment: you might have multiple Python 3 versions, and it may be getting installed on the wrong one.

Comment: @mechanical_meat, yes three different python3 versions, they all have requests installed now , but the terminal is outputing a traceback from import requests to   File "/Users/jack/Sites/python/socket.py", line 5, in <module>
    mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_INET' (most likely due to a circular import)